# Specifying Function Argument by Type

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm sure this is pretty obvious, but bear with me, I'm new to this stuff and it's not clicking.
So I've, like many other people, been trying to get my head around Monads. I've gotten to the point where I'm comfortable with the >>= and return operators and so forth. But I feel like I won't really understand it until I get behind it and do some writing myself.

Consequently, I've been playing with trying to implement the bind >>= operator for the List as a composition of map and foldr. For example, `[5,6,7,8] >>= (\x -> [x*5, x*6, x*7])` yields `[25,30,35,30,36,42,35,42,49,40,48,56]`. This looks a lot like the composition of a map and a fold. But if I try something like `foldr (++) [] . map` I get the obvious type error that map doesn't have type `[a] -> [[a]]` as expected. Of course, if I instead use something like `map (\x -> [x*5, x*6, x*7])` as the right argument to the composition operator it all works.

But it would be a hassle to specify a specific function every time; somehow the >>= operator behaves in a more general fashion. Is there a way to specify an argument by its type? Like, can I somehow tell map to only take functions of the type `a -> [a]` in this composition? Do I need to write a function that has type `(a -> [a]) -> [a] -> [[a]]` from scratch because there isn't really a way to narrow the map function to the type of function I want?

Also, please feel free to tell me I'm approaching this all wrong. I am still pretty new to this type of stuff. If so, please point me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check the type of something like

```
> :t \f -> foldr (++) [] . map f
```

in GHCi as I did above you'll notice something interesting

```
\f -> foldr (++) [] . map f :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Or, to cut to the chase, it turns out that the input function `f` *already* and *naturally* has the more restricted type you asked for. Why is this the case?

Let's examine `foldr (++) []` which is more naturally called `concat`

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat = foldr (++) []
```

we see that its input must be that of a list of lists. If we consider what that means in the context of post composition with `map`

```
concat           ::        [[c]] -> [c]
       . map f   :: [a] -> [ b ]          -- for (f :: a -> b)
```

we can see that `b` must be the same as `[c]` for some type `c`. In other words, information about the use of the result of mapping `f`, e.g. its passage through `concat`, has *flowed backwards* to specialize the information we know about `map` and even its argument `f`.

So, unifying `b` and `[c]` above we see that `map` must have a slightly more restrictive type

```
map ::* (a -> [c]) -> [a] -> [[c]]
```

where I write `(::*)` to indicate that this is a *specialization* of `map`'s natural type carried out naturally by *unification* with the type of `concat`.

Comment: Damn, Haskell is smart; smarter than I am. It's weird getting use to that. Thank you, answer accepted. This is brilliant.